# Passwords being stored as sha1 and pbkdf2_sha256

Tags: python, django

I have a django `auth_user` table, and for some reason, some of the passcodes are stores as `sha1$...` and others `pbkdf2_sha256$...`. I don't see any rhyme or reason to it -- what is the difference between these two and why would some be stored as one version, but others as another?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you perhaps upgrade from Django 1.3 to Django 1.4 while retaining user data?  Django 1.4 introduced the newer, more secure hash for password storage, but should still be backwards-compatible with the old hashes as far as I am aware.

Comment: Django always maintains backwards compatibility for passwords, it will 'upgrade' the password security the next time someone logs in, or changes their password. This means, unless you explicitly set the desired method to an older one, that if you downgrade to 1.3 those users won't be able to log in, and would probably need to follow a lost password process.